# How to provide permission to HMS Core App?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am unable to see **HMS Core App** on my **HMS device**. How Can Provide location and other permission TO HMS Core app?

Answer (score 1):

HMS core app should be there by default in HMS devices. To give permission for HMS Core App we have to go to
**Settings->Apps** and search for 'HMS Core'and grant the location or other permissions which are required.